# PageNotFound:1136 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, internationalization

I get WARN  PageNotFound:1136 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/CATestSlotBooking/show] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring', when I click any link from welcome.jsp.

Below is the controller class

```
@Controller
public class BookingSlotController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/show", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showBookingPage(ModelMap model) {
    BookingSlotVO bookingDetailsVO = new BookingSlotVO();
    model.addAttribute("bookingSlotVO", bookingDetailsVO);
    return "booking";
}
```

Dispatcher servlet MXL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cts" />

<bean id="viewResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
<property name="defaultLocale" value="en" ></property>
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
<bean id="localChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
<property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>OnlineTestSlotBooking</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Welcome.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>Welcome.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>Welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

welcome.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome page</title>
</head>

<body>
<p> CA Enablement Assessments </p>
<hr>

<a href="show">Book a slot for assessment</a>

<div style="text-align: right; background-color: yellow ">
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/show?lang=en" >Login(English) 
</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/show?lang=es" >Login(Spanish) 
 </a>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

When I click on any link in welcome.jsp, I get 404 error. If I change URL pattern to /* or *.do in web.xml, I don't get welcome.jsp page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `<welcome-file-list>` from the web.xml.

The updated `web.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>OnlineTestSlotBooking</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: No, this isn't working either. **No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/CATestSlotBooking/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'** error displayed.

Comment: Your project name is CATestSlotBooking_Skeleton -> url should be `/CATestSlotBooking_Skeleton/show`

Comment: Do run as server. Then, check what url eclipse is creating for you.

Comment: I did run as server and this is the URL eclipse produced "http://localhost:8088/CATestSlotBooking// ". But wlecome.jsp page is not displayed. If I change URL pattern to \ from \\*, welcome.jsp is displayed but not able to proceed from welcome page.

Comment: No, that's not possible. Please check which project are you running ? Have you tried this `localhost:8088/CATestSlotBooking_Skeleton/` url ? Please check. It should open the welcome.jsp. Note : Remove `<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Welcome.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>Welcome.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>Welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>` from web.xml.

Comment: It worked after removing <welcome-file-list>. Thank you so much